# Appending to JSON notation?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
   method: 'post',
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   parameters: {
          "javax.faces.ViewState": encodedViewState,
          "client-id": options._clientId,
          "component-value": options._componentValue
   }
});
```

Now, I would like to be able to append to the "Parameters" object programattically, but I am unsure of how I would actually do this.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply assign to it. But you might want to do that before creating the request.

```
var parameters = {
      "javax.faces.ViewState": encodedViewState,
      "client-id": options._clientId,
      "component-value": options._componentValue
}
parameters.foo = 'bar';

var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url, {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    parameters: parameters
});
```

Comment: just a note: another way to do the same thing is parameters["foo"] = "bar". I prefer this way because parameters.foo does not exist (yet), and it feels very "violating" to do the assignment that way :)

Comment: except that it's exactly the same thing, and your method requires interpretation at run-time as opposed to parse-time (meaning a preparsed function can't work off the interpreted value)

err.. did that make sense?

Comment: dot syntax is just syntactic sugar, they are the exact same thing, interpretation is run-time in both cases. Property lookup is dynamic whether you use a.b or a['b']

Answer (score 3):

Assume that the JSON object is named as obj in the Ajax.Request Javascript function. You could now add to the parameters object like this:

```
obj['parameters']['someproperty'] = 'somevalue';
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can't append to it after you call *new*, because Prototype automatically sends and starts processing the Ajax request upon creation, instead do something like this if you need to alter the parameters object:

```
var params = {
      "javax.faces.ViewState": encodedViewState,
      "client-id": options._clientId,
      "component-value": options._componentValue
      // Either add your additional properties here as:
      // propertyName : propertyValue
};
// Or add your properties here as:
// params.propertyName = propertyValue;
new Ajax.Request(url, {

method: 'post',

contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

parameters: params
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I used to append to the JSON object's existing `data` attribute, but I needed it to be generic enough to handle different key-value pairs.  Here's what I created based on this post which seems to work for me.

```
doAction : function(mData){
    this.data = mData;
    this.appendData = function(mDataToAppend){
        var jsonStrAr = JSON.stringify(mDataToAppend).replace('{','').replace('}','').split('","');
        for(var v = 0; v < jsonStrAr.length; v++){
            var m = jsonStrAr[v].split(':');
            this.data[m[0].replace(/"/g,'')] = m[1].replace(/"/g,'');
        }
    }
}
```

The result is a single JSON object with *n* to many attributes, which can then be sent over to the server via the `JSON.stringify()` command in the ajax request.  Still getting comfortable/thinking with JSON, so there might be a better way to do this - in which case, I'm all ears.